# ./bootstrap: 17: exec: autoreconf: not found : OpenTSDB installation

Tags: ubuntu, hbase, opentsdb

I am trying to install OpenTSDB on Ubuntu, and I am following [this documentation](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/installation.html). But after running these commands:

```
git clone git://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb.git
cd opentsdb
```

running this commanding is giving the following console output:

```
./build.sh
```

Console Output:

```
seed-admin@seedadmin-Inspiron-3847:~/Abharthan/opentsdb$ sudo ./build.sh
+ test -f configure
+ ./bootstrap
./bootstrap: 17: exec: autoreconf: not found
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install autoconf` solved my problem